# When user re-buy in app purchase, the paymentQueue::updatedTransactions should be called by iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When user re-buy in app purchase, the paymentQueue::updatedTransactions should be called  by iOS ?

The situation is :
if the user re-buy product, nothing is being called in code, so I can't "open" the content to full version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paymentQueue::updatedTransactions should get called. If product is non consumable or auto-renew able subscription then apple will not deduct money and transaction will fail. So for non consumable product OR auto new subscription you have to restore transaction.
For subscriptions and consumable product you have to handle it.

I am not sure weather I am solving you problem or not. So please post some code or some more details if you need further assistance.

Comment: my current version is 4.3.1. 
I'm upgrading to 4.3.5 to see if this will fix the problem and I wasted some few hours on this.

maybe small question, just to be sure :
if purchasing the first time is working o.k with updateTransacations, there is no reason this method at least will be called, when re-buy product, right ?

Comment: no luck. upgrade to 4.3.5 did not fix the problem.
I don't understand why after click "OK" on the msgbox "you've already purchased this in-app purchase but it hasn't been downloaded." the updatedTransactions not called.

Comment: BINGO- 2 tutorials did not mentions this, the third did:
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];|